# Problema ao tentar atualizar instância de objeto com Realm

Tags: swift, realmdb

Fiz uma requisição na base local e recebi um array com os dados.
Depois percorro o array com looping for, procurando um objeto com um id específico, ao localizar o objeto tento atualizar uma propriedade, porém o Realm dispara o seguinte erro:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call
>   beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

Código que gera o erro:

```
var arrayObjects: Results<MyModel>?

viewDidLoad(){

    arrayObjects = managerLocalDB.getAllData()

}

// Depois ...

    func registerNewStatus(status: Bool, id: Int) {

        for abrTmp in arrayObjects!{

            if abrTmp.id == id{

                abrTmp.selecionado = status

            }

        }

    }
```

Pelo que vi, o Realm atualiza as instâncias de suas requisições ao ter modificações no registro. Porém não quero que o registro seja atualizado até enviar os dados para o servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para atualizar um objeto Realm você tem que definir um dos atributos com o id do objeto, ou melhor dizendo, a chave primaria deste objeto:

Exemplo da chave primária do objeto

```
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Colocando a classe do objeto com um `primaryKey` vocè tem que fazer com que o objeto seja atualizado quando você quiser. Sempre que quiser fazer um atualização de dados você deve então marcar a tranzação para que o obejto seja atualizado.

```
let cheeseBook = Book()
cheeseBook.title = "Cheese recipes"
cheeseBook.price = 9000
cheeseBook.id = 1

// Updating book with id = 1
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(cheeseBook, update: true)
}
```

Neste exemplo acima, ele vai atualizar o valor do objeto que tenha o `id` igual a 1

Caso você não queria criar um novo objeto para que assim faça todo o parser dele tem um maneira mais fácil.

Exemplo abaixo ele atualiza o valor booleano de um obejto no realm.

```
let objeto= realm.objects(ObjetoMeu).first

try! realm.write {     
   objeto!.valorBool= true                
}
```

Para mais informações eu recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação que é muito boa:

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-objects

Comment: Cheguei a mesma conclusão depois de pesquisar um pouco, mas vc ja adiantou a resposta!! Obrigado Lucas!